# PHPMyAdmin Cannot insert data. Error 1452

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1452

Ok so I'm trying to insert data into the customers table and I keep getting a 1452 error. All tables are running InnoDB. The customers table has a foreign key from plan. Sorry for the lack of information, but I'm new to this. I'm trying to include everything I can to help.

Below is a link to sql export of the database
http://www.mediafire.com/?ur41lys1e5es2i1

[image: 1452 error when inserting data][image: Relationship of Foreign Key][image: Plans Table][image: Customers Table]

Link to the above images for better viewing.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/805/errorcustomers.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/193/relationship.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/29/planstable.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/845/customertable.png/

Please Help,

Thanks

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if the SQL was legible in the screenshots

Comment: Updated with links to original images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is telling you that there is no 'none' plan in the plans table; which is backed up with the query of the table.

Because of the foreign key constraints, you need to create the plans before the customers that reference them.

Comment: Thanks alot :) why is it always the most simple things :P